# NAND-Flash-SSD Management

Tags: memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, flash-memory, solid-state-drive

Is that correct that, in NAND-Flash-SSD if you put some data in one page, you can not put an update for the specific data into the same flash-page until it gets removed? Let's assume that: I put 2KB data in a 4KB Flash-page and i want to overwrite that previous data and do not  want to use a new fresh page for that because i have still enough space on that previous page. Can i handle that like i mentioned above, Or do i have to use a complete fresh page because of the out-place strategy that uses a new page for every update?

Answer (score 0):

Some NAND Flash support this feature.
we call it as changing colum program, you can program the data start from sepcial column.